# Windows Boot Manager, linking a 'device' to boot linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, bcdedit

I'm attempting to boot linux on a UEFI-GPT machine with a Windows Boot Manager (WBM).

So far I have installed Archlinux (Arch) with Grub. The grubx64.efi is successfully on my windows boot partition and I can see the option to use it in UEFI-BIOS, selecting this loads grub and I'm able to get into Arch fine.

**I have noticed that in the Windows Boot Manager, selecting from the splash screen, 'Change defaults or choose other options' > 'Choose other options' > 'Use a device', shows the boot options as in UEFI-BIOS, in my case grub shows as 'Linux'. Selecting 'Linux' reboots the computer and loads grub then Arch.**

[image]

**Is there anyway to use this entry for the device 'Linux' to show directly on the WBM splash screen under the entry for Windows 8.1?** Ideally i'd like the 'Arch Linux' to link to the 'Linux' device.

[image]

Guidance with bcdedit appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Use a device" in the image above lists boot entries from NVRAM (CSM is enabled as BIOS devices are shown as well as Linux boot entry).

There is no known way to start successfully a non-Windows EFI loader entry in BCD from Windows boot manager.

EFI boot manager (in firmware) can start any EFI application from ESP, Windows boot manager- bootmgr.efi starts only memtest.efi and winload.efi successfully AFAIK.

For booting directly any device or installed OS(Windows, Linux) on UEFI(and BIOS) from Windows 8.1/7 you can use [BootNext](http://www.boyans.net/bootnext/bootnext.html) tool.

Comment: This is true, I am now using rEFInd in my ESP, which loads WBM and Linux.